# window.postMessage in ionic typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, postmessage

I have this javascript code for postmessage that works fine in web:

```
<script>
    var popup;
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {  
              console.log(e.origin);    
            if (popup != null) {
                var reply = JSON.stringify( {'msg' : 'Message' } );
                popup.postMessage(reply, e.origin);
            }
        });
    function openRemotePage() {
        popup = window.open('website.com' );
    }
</script>
```

I want to have similar functionality in Ionic-typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public static popup:any;
  public openRemotePage():void{
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if (MyModal.popup!= null) {
        var reply = JSON.stringify( {'msg' : 'Message' } );
        MyModal.popup.postMessage(reply, e.origin);
    }
  });
  MyModal.popup = window.open('website.com');
  }
```